# How to extract a sub portion of a large video file

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg, xuggle, xuggler

I want to extract a small portion of video from a large video file on the basis of a given start and end time.

My internet search shows that many suggest using Xuggle to do this, but I am unfamiliar with this library, its use, or how one can use it to achieve my goals. Please help me with this.

Comment: Have you had a look at the [Xuggle Tutorials](http://wiki.xuggle.com/Tutorials) and the [Xuggle API](http://build.xuggle.com/view/Stable/job/xuggler_jdk5_stable/javadoc/java/api/index.html)? The documentation looks to be pretty good.

Comment: Yeah , i looked at both of them , but actually i want some guidance , if any one give me start or give me the direction , then it can be helpful for me...... If you know about that please give me some support...

Comment: I'm no pro on use of Xuggle, so I'm probably not the one to give you the best help, but I am pretty experienced with StackOverflow, and my experience here is that if you post your code attempt and then note problems that you are having with this attempt, you'll often get better and faster help. Much luck!

Comment: *"give me the direction"* Seems like if 2 links to the relevant docs. is not enough to get you started to the point that you can ask a *specific* question (i.e. give you a direction), you should focus on simpler things for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

try reading the [manual](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Generic-options)!

-ss and -t    will start at ss and copy for '-t'...

```
ffmpeg -i test.mpg -r 25 -ss 00:00:10 -t 00:00:05 images%05d.png
```

starts 10 seconds in for 5 seconds