# VLCj extract portion of video

Tags: video, vlc, vlcj

I would like to extract portions of a video clip and put [copy] them into a new file. I read another question [How to extract a sub portion of a large video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177747/how-to-extract-a-sub-portion-of-a-large-video-file) that suggested using Xuggle or FFmpeg but is there any way to do this with VLCJ (or the command line of VLC)?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solution: use the following code to play the portion:

`mediaPlayer.playMedia(media, ":start-time=30", ":stop-time=60");`

and add ":sout…" to save the portion.

Comment: That approach generally works, and I've had that working on Linux for sure, but I tried that recently on OSX with some 1080p mp4 and bizarrely it seemed that the fragment of video between start-time and end-time was actually cut from the resultant video, or there was some other weirdness in the resultant video.

Comment: @caprica I tried to perform that but it stops the current running video and does not generate output file. Then, I also tried to follow the test from https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/blob/master/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/streaming/StreamHttp.java  , I changed parameters as requirement but still no output is generated. However, using headless browser does not stop running video.
can you please help me with this?

Comment: @caprica  Note : I am trying to copy a file locally. And I used following VLC generated command while achieving this with streaming from VLC application on Windows 64 bit, with java 8 64 bit and it worked through application.
 :sout=#file{dst=E:\\Whistle.mp4,no-overwrite} :no-sout-all :sout-keep